# All possible pairings in a sample and assumptions of logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, independence

We have a debated issue in our area of research that I am hoping you can help me with. I'm part of a group of researchers who research crime linkage and, in particular, the assumptions that underpin it. One method we use is to take a sample of solved serial crimes and we create all possible pairings. Some of these pairs are two crimes by the same offender and other pairs represent two crimes by two different offenders. For each pair we measure the degree of similarity in their crime scene behavior (quantified using a similarity coefficient). Each pair therefore has a similarity value. We then run a logistic regression analysis (leave-one-out) with pair type as the outcome variable and similarity "score" as the independent variable. One question we have considered is whether our pairs represent independent observations. The same pairing is not duplicated in our datasets, but the same crime will contribute to more than one pairing. Each pairing is therefore a distinct entity but I'm sure you can see our caution around this. I'd welcome any insights you have.